# How can I prevent a change in value of upper 8-bit ASCII when storing a byte array to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8

I am working directly with a device that I need to be able to send 8-bit ASCII. I am trying save a byte array that may have values greater than 127 to a string. These values are being converted to 0xfffd instead of the zero prefixed character I expect.

For example I would expect that with the example below the third char in the string would be `0x00AA` but in reality it is `0xffdd`.

If I do a direct assignment it works.

```
test = "ABC" + (char)0xAA + "DEF";
```

I’ve tried alternate encodings such as `"windows-1250"` with differing results (`0x201a`), but not what I want. Picking an ASCII encoding fails (`0x003f`) as well.

How can I get the correct conversion?

Sample code:

```
  byte[] byteArray = new byte[30];

  byteArray[0] = 0x41; // A
  byteArray[1] = 0x42; // B
  byteArray[2] = 0x43; // C
  byteArray[3] = 0xAA; // Special character in upper 128 character set
  byteArray[4] = 0x44; // D
  byteArray[5] = 0x45; // E
  byteArray[6] = 0x46; // F

  string test = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray).TrimEnd('\0');
  if (!test.Equals("ABC" + (char)0xAA + "DEF")) {
    // It fails
    // test[3] == 0xfffd not 0x00aa
  }
```

Comment: **Why** are you calling something from `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` if you're using ASCII?  That will turn anything past code point 127 to a multi-byte character!

Comment: If you want to do ASCII, why do you use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: I thought that without it the byte array would be treated as UTF-16.

Comment: Internally, C# `char` and `string` types are UTF-16.  There's nothing you can really do about that.  The important thing is to convert the string to the appropriate encoding when reading it from a different location (such as a file or stream) or writing it to a different location (such as a file or stream).

Comment: I agree. That is why I tried to find an encoding that said treat each byte of the array as a single unit (basically an 8-bit char) and convert it to a zero prefixed UTF-16 char that a string will happily hold for me.

Comment: What do you need? 8-bit ASCII or UTF-16? You have claimed both.

Comment: @usr All strings are UTF-16 so the goal is to store the byte array unmodified (other than then 0 prefix) as UTF-16. I'm using strings because they are very handy character containers.

Comment: There's no such thing as 8 bit ASCII. ASCII is a 7 bit encoding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand what you are saying, but many printers use the full 8-bit character set. The lower 7 being standard ASCII.  I need to address all 8 bits.  That's why I tried to use the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: You just want to send 8-bit 'ASCII' strings to the device? In that case, you need to know which codepage the device uses. Then you can just create and use the string as normal and then finally convert it to the correct code page. Now, that only works if you really want to send strings. If you want to mix strings with control bytes or the likes, then you're better off not using a string and using only byte arrays.

Comment: @MicroVirus Keeping with the byte arrays is a possibility. The solution I posted below will work for this specific case.

Comment: How do you want to use it? What is it that you are exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: The source is stored in a text file with a handful of directives and variable place holders. There are things like comments that are removed completely. This examination is all done up front when the file is loaded. When it's time to send the data to the device, the final text is constructed, inserting the target variable values along the way. This is used to send data to a high speed near real-time system that we can't depend on use Windows printing. I've had similar systems we routinely did in older versions of Delphi before having to deal with the Unicode strings.

Comment: It's simple not to deal with Unicode strings in .NET. Just don't use the types String and Char (C#: string and char).

Answer (score -1):

I think my problem is that no matter what "encoding" I use it will try and remap characters to match the target. Manually casting each byte as a `char` solves my issue.

Usage: `string test = ByteArrayToString(byteArray);`

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert a zero terminated byte array to a string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="byteArray"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string ZeroTerminatedByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
{
  // This routine is used to map a byte array unmodified to a string
  // Each character is stored with as a double byte with leading zero.
  // Using the encodings to convert will try and remap some characters
  // System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("437").GetString(byteArray);
  // System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);

  string result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++) {
    if (byteArray[i] == 0) { break; }
    result = result + (char)byteArray[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This makes no real sense

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What doesn't make sense? This routine stores all of the bytes in the array to the string without changing any of the bytes like the different encodings I tried.

Comment: It's possible that CP437 could help you here because every sequence of any value 0-255 is valid CP437. Each byte would be converted to/from a single UTF-16 code unit. When you are searching for or replacing, just be sure to use the appropriate UTF-16 code unit instead of the byte value. For example, the CP437 codepoint 170 is stored as 0xAA and it corresponds to the Unicode codepoint  U+00AC, which is one UTF-16 code unit 0x00AC.

Comment: The values > 127 will be mistreated. You have to know what your 8 bit encoding really is.